# H2OConnectionError: Not connected to a cluster

Tags: import, h2o, google-colaboratory

hi guys recently i've encounter this problem in google colab, and i dont know how to solve this problem

```
import h2o
h2o.init

data_train = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=14OYzA93IkuKPlkdvXs9Od53HyopgSQ2u"
data_train_df = h2o.import_file(path=data_train)
```

i following a book that suggest these following codes, but somehow it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

The h2o package is not automatically installed in Google Colab. If you attempt to run `import h2o` without installing it, you will get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-accdebc0c7de> in <module>()
----> 1 import h2o

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h2o'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Based on the error message you can then start a new code block and run `!pip install h2o` to install the package. Then, running `import h2o` should be successful.

One more thing to keep in mind is that you need to include parentheses to call a function. Running `h2o.init` will return the description `<function h2o.h2o.init>`. Try `h2o.init()` to initialize an h2o cluster.

Edit: The “not connected to a cluster”  means you have not initialized a cluster. Try the `h2o.init()` command again, but using parenthesis so that the function is called and not printed.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i've already installed h2o package but still encounter the problem. what i have to do next?